# Object FIles in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Please help me to understand **Object Files** in **Apache Spark** in detail. I could not find sufficient information on the internet regarding the same.
Thank you.

Comment: can you please add more context and external references of what you are trying to understand?

Comment: Yes, certainly. I was reading about loading and saving data from different file formats into Spark. I came across sequence files and Object files. The explanation provided there was not clear to me. I am trying to understand and visualize what are Object Files, how they are used etc.

Comment: External reference of what I'm trying to understand: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=234&v=ksshL2vSriY&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=CloudxLab

Comment: @Vzzarr This is the reference...    https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=234&v=ksshL2vSriY&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=CloudxLab